# fgets inside loop does not wait for input after encountered EOF

Tags: c, linux, fgets

I use fgets inside a while loop for getting use input, if I use ctrl-d to send a EOF at the begining of line, then fgets return NULL(because it encountered EOF), and terminal print "!!!", but the problem is after that the fgets function does not wait for input, the terminal keep printing "ERROR" until loop ends. I was expecting the fgets will wait for input every loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int argNums = 0;
    while(argNums < 20){
        char argBuf[100];
        if(fgets(argBuf, 100, stdin) != NULL){
            printf("!!!");
        }else{
            printf("ERROR ");
            //exit(1);
        }
        argNums++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is output

```
1
!!!2
!!!ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR ERROR
```

I want to know why this happens, thanks for helping.

Comment: It is because you have not consumed argNums. You loop until it reaches 20.

Comment: Add the `fgets` call to the loop condition, so you check both `argNums` *and* for errors (like `EOF`) as part of the loop continuing.

Comment: You can consider using feof() and clearerr() if you want to loop again after "CTRL-D" ?

Comment: @RachidK. I know it will loop 20 times, the question is it does not wait for my input after i send EOF to fgets

Comment: See the answer below : use clearerr().

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know it's better to add fgets to condition check, I just want to know why fgets inside loop stop wait for input if I send EOF,

Comment: @RachidK. so the EOF will stay in the stdin after the first fgets right? am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes. Hence the reference to the manual of clearerr() added by @David Ranieri in my answer below

Comment: @RachidK. thank you !. if I use read system call, not through FILE * stuff, is clearerr() stll necessary?

Comment: Why? Because when you have reached the end of the file then there's nothing more to read. `EOF` leads to a flag inside the file stream to be set, and once set all input will fail. That's how it's supposed to work, you just can't input more once you've sent the `EOF` from the terminal. Perhaps you should rethink your way of handling end of *input* (as opposed to end of file), for example by asking the user to give some specific input that marks the end (like e.g. and empty line).

Comment: Also note that no standard C stream input function will return a value that makes it possible to differ between error or end of file. You must use the `feof` and `ferror` functions to check which it was.

Comment: Through read(), you are at the "low level" : You will need to loop on read() until you get the terminating end of line ("\n"). Upon CTRL-D, read() will return 0, but you will loop again (you don't have any EOF/error condition stored in the "stream" context as said by @Someprogrammerdude). But read() blocks until you fill the buffer (so you need to adjust the buffer size). Even if you type CTRL-D, you will need to type RETURN after it. Have fun...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use clearerr():

> The C library function void clearerr(FILE *stream) clears the
> end-of-file and error indicators for the given stream.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int argNums = 0;
    while(argNums < 20){
        char argBuf[100];
        if(fgets(argBuf, 100, stdin) != NULL){
            printf("!!!");
        }else{
            printf("ERROR ");
            clearerr(stdin);
            //exit(1);
        }
        argNums++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a note for the OP to check if it's really and end-of-file condition before clearing the error. If it's really is an actual error, then clearing that status won't help much.